# Problema con BottomNavigationBar en Flutter: no cambia el color del texto de las opciones no seleccionadas

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo problemas con `BottomNavigationBar` en Flutter. Estoy tratando de cambiar el color del texto de las opciones no seleccionadas, pero no importa lo que haga, el color del texto sigue siendo el mismo. He intentado establecer `unselectedItemColor` y `unselectedLabelStyle`, pero ninguno parece funcionar. También he intentado cambiar el color de fondo de `BottomNavigationBar` y parece funcionar, pero el color del texto sigue siendo el mismo.

También lo he intentado, sacando `BottomNavigationBar` de `AppBar` y colocándolo con la propiedad `BottomNavigationBar:` `navSuper()` Esta no es la idea de diseño, pero quería probarla y tampoco funcionó.

Aquí está el código que tengo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("title"),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(39, 73, 140, 1),
        leading: Icon(Icons.add_alert),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0),
          child: navSuper(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

BottomNavigationBar navSuper() {
  return BottomNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
    unselectedItemColor: Color.fromARGB(132, 0, 0, 0),
    unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 5, 5),
      fontSize: 16,
    ),
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Inicio"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person_add), label: "Registro"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.book), label: "Moodle"),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.stay_current_landscape_sharp), label: "Aula"),
    ],
  );
}
```

No sé cómo resolverlo, hice lo mejor que pude con mis habilidades de google y le pregunté a chatgpt y según chatgpt el código es correcto, pero estoy seguro de que hice algo mal, ya que estoy aprendiendo flutter recientemente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo varias cosas, primero debes declarar una variable de tipo `int` para manejar el indice de cada item:

```
int index = 0;
```

Luego en el `BottomNavigationBar` le asignas el indice en la propiedad `currentIndex` y en la propiedad `onTap` le asignas un `setState` para actualizar el estado del widget:

```
 BottomNavigationBar navSuper() {
return BottomNavigationBar(
  //type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
  currentIndex: index,
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
  onTap: (value) {
    setState(() => index = value);
  },
  unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
  unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 5, 5),
    fontSize: 16,
  ),
  items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Inicio"),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_add), label: "Registro"),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.book), label: "Moodle"),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.stay_current_landscape_sharp), label: "Aula"),
  ],
  //currentIndex: 2,
);
```

}

Si ves bien el código, te darás cuenta que tengo una línea comentada `type:BottomNavigationBarType.fixed`, para que funcione el `backgroundColor` es necesario que descomentes esta línea, porque siempre que los item del `bottomNavigationBar` sean mayor a 3 el tipo cambiará automáticamente a `shifting` y si no se cambia el tipo de `bottomNavigationBar` a `fixed` entonces sobrescribirá el color de fondo siempre.

Espero mi respueta te haya ayudado.

Comment: Eres el crack de los crack, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad foreground de TextStyle en selectedLabelStyle.

> Si se especifica [foreground], este valor [color] debe ser nulo. La propiedad [color] es una abreviatura de Paint()..color = color.

Por lo tanto, si se especifica "foreground", se ignorará la propiedad "color" en su lugar y se utilizará el valor de "foreground".

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      selectedItemColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
          foreground: Paint()..color = Colors.deepPurple.shade300),
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.deepPurple.shade100,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Inicio"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_add), label: "Registro"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.book), label: "Moodle"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.stay_current_landscape_sharp), label: "Aula"),
      ],
    ),
```

En caso de que desees ver los labels que no estan seleccionados solo establece la propiedad showUnselectedLabels en true y establece el estilo que desees tambien a los labels

```
showUnselectedLabels: true,
```

---

```
unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
        foreground: Paint()..color =  Colors.deepPurple.shade100
      ),
```