# BottomNavigationBar no cambia de color flutter backgroundcolor

Tags: flutter

Estoy teniendo dificultades para cambiar el color de fondo del *BottomNavigationBar* en Flutter. He intentado establecer el color directamente usando la propiedad *backgroundColor*, así como intentar obtener el color del tema usando `Theme.of(context).primaryColor`, pero el color no cambia.

He configurado el tema principal de la aplicación con el color deseado, y otros elementos de la interfaz de usuario están tomando este color correctamente. Sin embargo, el *BottomNavigationBar* parece ignorar la configuración de color.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        selectedItemColor:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Inicio',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            label: 'Comprar',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
            label: 'Vende',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
            label: 'Mi Caja',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Cuenta',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: pruebas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta es sencilla, debes agregar la propiedad type:

```
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
```

Anteriormente ya había respondido una pregunta similar con un poco más de información:

[respuesta BottomNavigationBar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/593215/226957)

Al final de mi respuesta verás la razón